# Node-gyp on openshift compile fails

Tags: node.js, openshift

I am trying to get a sailsjs project installed on openshift. The project has a bunch of dependencies, and one of those dependencies has a dependency on bcrypt. When I try to install on openshift by pushing from git, I see an error during the bcrypt build phase of

```
node-gyp rebuild
```

The error is

```
"This version of node/NAN/v8 requires a C++11 compiler"
```

Is there any way for me to get around this? I saw this related question : [Building modules using node-gyp on Openshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31311495/building-modules-using-node-gyp-on-openshift)

However, using rhc ssh into my app, and running those commands, I wasn't able to get `node-gyp configure` to run either

I saw some other answers that said to switch to bcryptjs, but I don't want to change code in the dependencies of my project.